# Is package-lock.json useless in npm 5.6.0? Should I commit it?

Tags: node.js, git

I've read a lot about it, there are tons of questions here on SO about how it worked before npm 5.1.0, and some about how it works now, but I can't find a definitive answer to what exactly is its purpose now, and if one should commit it or not.

As I see it, `package-lock.json` is almost uselss now (node 5.6.0), I can't see any benefit in committing it, it may even be counterproductive because it may lead to merge conflicts.

Official documentation has not been updated to reflect the changes https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks so it's... Useless.

Note that I'm new to node, I might have misunderstood something, if soo please correct me.

Comment: Why is the lock file useless? It's critical for `npm ci` to be performant.

Comment: @evolutionxbox My team is using 5.6.0 so `ci` does not exist (it was introduced in 5.7.1 I read) but thanks for pointing it out, I will see if we can upgrade. By the way, the question can then change to "was `package-json.lock` useless between 5.1.0 and 5.7.1?"

Comment: Ah. Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8) can help? (It looks helpful so far)

Comment: That article talks about 5.x.x but I'm quite sure it is actually referring to whatever was between 5.0.0 and 5.1.0, becouse either I'm reading it wrong (quite possible) or it's wrong. As you said, `npm ci` uses `package-lock.json` (but it's not available until 5.7.0) while `npm install` (between 5.1.0 and 5.7.0) overwrites it, using `package.json` instead. I can't see how the content of the article can be true given the behaviour of `npm install`

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. I guess one benefit is that it's there "in case you need to know the exact set of versions used, with which the project functioned as intended". But yeah, unless you're using npm 5.7.0+ (and make use of npm ci), it doesn't seem of practical use for the majority of cases.